# Htaccess cookie based on the URI

Tags: .htaccess

I have to set a cookie if my URL contains r=([a-zA-z0-9]) at the end.

Ex,

> http://www.example.com/welcome/r=15 OR 
>   http://www.example.com/contact/site-admin/r=17

If i hit the above urls I need to drop a cookies like request => 15, request => 17 respectively.
request => cookie name and 15 & 17 are values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !request=[0-9]+ [NC]
RewriteRule /r=([0-9]+)/?$ - [L,CO=request:$1:%{HTTP_HOST}]
```